# Multiple Checkerboard detection OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

Is there a way to detect multiple checkerboards (with the same dimensions if required) in a single image in OpenCV?

Comment: Just as a quick thought, if there isn't a direct way you can work around the limitation by detecting one checkerboard, then removing it from the image (e.g. painting it over in white), then running detection again etc.

Comment: Yeah thats not a bad idea.